# Why try catch in programming method is not working?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm having a headache with this problem. I can't accomplished that my try can catch my exception. Here is the picture.

[image]

In a moment, I was experimenting with this. And it works..

```
            var task = client.GetAsync(uri);
            try
            {
                task.Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

But the problem with above is the UI freezes. And I don't want that. What could I do?

Comment: Unrelated note: Don't use `throw ex;`. Use `throw;`. It will re-throw the exception without resetting the stack.

Comment: All right, thanks for the point!

Comment: Maybe you have enabled exception break: Go to Debug/Exceptions... and deselect "Thrown" column of "Common Runtime Language Exception"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Never call `task.Wait()`.

`task.Wait()` will synchronously wait for the task to finish.
That will freeze the UI.

Your catch block is working, but you're seeing the exception before it gets caught.
Uncheck the checkbox and try again, and the catch block should be triggered.

Comment: That's true SLaks, thanks a lot!! I spent more of 4 hours with this problem and it was so easy. It works!

Comment: The explanation is sound, but I think *never* might be a little too strong.

Comment: I think ["never" is fine](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). Not only does `Wait` synchronously block, but it is also a common cause of deadlocks *and* wraps any errors within an `AggregateException`. `Wait` is just a holdover from the TPL (and if you're doing synchronous parallel programming, `Wait` is OK); it should never be used with `async` code.

Comment: @MgSam As with any absolutes about programming, there will be exceptions. But using `Wait()` and `await` together in one program is a really bad idea, as others mentioned, unless you're sure you know what you're doing. I can think of only one case where it may be okay: waiting for an `async` method from `Main()` of a console application (which can't be `async`).

Comment: So what @DarfZon should do ?? I understand you shouting 'Never say never' slogan but what about problem solving ? So Task.WaitAll() will synchronously wait for all threads/task and ? What @DarfZon should do ? Not `wait` for Task ? So how to react to exception ?